# Why does stdafx.h work the way it does?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers, stdafx.h

As usual, when my brain's messing with something I can't figure out myself, I come to you guys for help :)

This time I've been wondering why stdafx.h works the way it does? To my understanding it does 2 things:

- Includes standard headers which we
  *might* (?) use and which are rarely changed
- Work as a compiler-bookmark for when
  code is no longer precompiled.

Now, these 2 things seems like two very different tasks to me, and I wonder why they didn't do two seperate steps to take care of them? To me it seems reasonable to have a #pragma-command do the bookmarking stuff and to optionally have a header-file a long the lines of windows.h to do the including of often-used headers... Which brings me to my next point: Why are we forced to include often-used headers through stdafx.h? Personally, I'm not aware of any often used headers I use that I'm not already doing my own includes for - but maybe these headers are necessary for .dll generation?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 6):

stdafx.h is ONE way of having Visual studio do precompiled headers. It's a simple to use, easy to automatically generate, approach that works well for smaller apps but can cause problems for larger more complex apps where the fact that it encourages, effectively, the use of a single header file it can cause coupling across components that are otherwise independent. If used ***just*** for system headers it tends to be OK, but as a project grows in size and complexity it's tempting to throw other headers in there and then suddenly changing any header file results in the recompilation of everything in the project.

See here: [[Is there a way to use pre-compiled headers in VC++ without requiring stdafx.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290034/is-there-a-way-to-use-pre-compiled-headers-in-vc-without-requiring-stdafxh#293219)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290034/is-there-a-way-to-use-pre-compiled-headers-in-vc-without-requiring-stdafxh#293219) for details of an alternative approach.

Answer (score 4):

You are not forced to use "stdafx.h". You can check off the Use precompiled headers in project properties (or when creating the project) and you won't need `stdafx.h` anymore.

The compiler uses it as a clue to be able to precompile most used headers separately in a `.pch` file to reduce compilation time (don't have to compile it every time).

Comment: Sorry Mehrdad, I re-read your question and answer and agree with you, I removed my comment before you posted yours.

If you edit your answer, I will gladly vote for you (it says that my vote is too old and requires you to edit your reply before I can change my vote)

Answer (score 1):

It keeps the compile time down, as the stuff in it are always compiled first (see details in quote below):

> stdafx.h is a file
>   that describes both standard system
>   and project specific include files
>   that are used frequently but hardly
>   ever changed.
>
> Compatible compilers will
>   pre-compile this file to reduce
>   overall compile times. **Visual C++ will
>   not compile anything before the
>   `#include "stdafx.h"` in the source file**, unless the compile option
>   /Yu'stdafx.h' is unchecked (by
>   default); it assumes all code in the
>   source up to and including that line
>   is already compiled.

Comment: I am not sure anybody but the first poster read the question properly.

Answer (score -5):

It will help reduce long compilations.

Comment: Read the question before to answer.