# #pragma hdrstop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

[Is there a way to use pre-compiled headers in VC++ without requiring stdafx.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290034/is-there-a-way-to-use-pre-compiled-headers-in-vc-without-requiring-stdafx-h)

Regarding the first answer to this question above,

I tried to implement his solution using visual studio 2010, and failed:

> fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?

Any ideas?

The objective is to NOT use `#include "StdAfx.h"` anywhere, but instead decide on whether or not to use it during compile time.

If /Yc or Yu are not used, `#pragma hdrstop` has no effect

If /Yu is used, `#pragma hdrstop` is replaced with `#include "StdAfx.h"`, or at least thats the claimed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you had option /Yu "StdAfx.h" when compiling.
The answer suggested to leave that "StdAfx.h" part of /Yu option blank.