# What does #pragma hdrstop without parameter do when used in multiple files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, precompiled-headers

What is the practical value ("what does it do") of putting `#pragma hdrstop` (no filename parameter) in a couple of source (cpp) files?

Note that the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/263e9b36%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are (once again) as clear as mud to me.

Edit/Note: I'm asking this, because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290034/is-there-a-way-to-use-pre-compiled-headers-in-vc-without-requiring-stdafx-h/293219#293219) and the article it links to seem to recommend that. But I do not understand what benefit it has to have a *separate* pch file for each compilation unit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to the original question is that the purpose of having #pragma hdrstop in a file with neither /Yc or /Yu set is that it's ignored and so you can set up a build configuration which builds without precompiled headers and other build configurations that build WITH precompiled headers and you don't need to change the code or the headers that are included at all to do so.

More detail...

The notes on MSDN say that "The hdrstop pragma gives you additional control over precompilation file names and over the location at which the compilation state is saved." which is true, but it's not especially obvious exactly how useful that can be...

In a nutshell.

- Putting #pragma hdrstop in a source file that isn't compiled with /Yc or /Yu has no effect at all.
- If you have /Yu set for the file then hdrstop tells the compiler to throw away everything before the line on which hdrstop appears and insert the precompiled header instead.
- If /Yc is set for the file then hdrstop means save all of the compiled state for everything up to the line on which hdrstop appears as the precompiled header.

The trick is using /Yc and /Yu without the optional header file name; just check the 'use' or 'create' radio button and leave the 'through header' edit box blank (or edit the project file...).

So you have 1 file, possibly called PrecompiledHeader.cpp which includes the headers that you want to include in the precompiled header and which has #pragma hdrstop at the end of the list of include files. This ONE file is compiled with /Yc.

You then have all your other cpp files with #pragma hdrstop after the include files that are in your precompiled header. These files are all compiled with /Yu.

This results in PrecompiledHeader.cpp building your (in this example) single pch file and all of the other files using that single pch file.

The advantage in doing this is that NONE of your files need to include a 'global' precompiled header building header file - so no stdafx.h or whatever. This means that you can set up a build configuration which builds WITHOUT precompiled headers where all of the #pragma hdrstop lines are simply ignored.

This is "good" because it means that you can have a single 'no precomp' build configuration which lets you develop quickly (you can change a single header and NOT force the world to rebuild) and other "normal" configurations that DO use precompiled headers.

Comment: Thanks. Thank you very much! ... Now, hmm ... *"You then have all your other cpp files with #pragma hdrstop after the include files that are in your precompiled header."* -- does this mean the other files need to know what's in the precompiled header so that they can split their includes to before and after the hdrstop line?

Comment: It works better if you do. But you don't have to. You WILL get build errors in your precomp builds if you have a file that is above the #pragma hdrstop that isn't in your precompiled header. You can then decide if it's used widely enough to warrant being in the precomp or not.

Answer (score 5):

All the code before `#pragma hdrstop` will be part of a precompiled header. If no filename parameter is given, the name of the header will be the base name of the source file with a .PCH extension, as mentioned in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/263e9b36%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The name of the precompiled header file is determined according to the
>   following rules, in order of precedence:
>
> 1. The argument to the /Fp compiler option
> 2. The filename argument to #pragma hdrstop
> 3. The base name of the source file with a .PCH extension

So, if you have that on a file named `blah.cpp` it will produce a file named `blah.pch`, IFF compiled with `/Yc` (which only one file should have set).

Comment: That's the kind of thing that happens when you bypass options 0, 1 and 2.  Using /Yu is pretty universal, option 0.

Answer (score 4):

If not using `#pragma hdrstop` in your C/C++ project, you muse have a dedicated .cpp file as the source file for the .pch created.

If using `#pragma hdrstop` in a .cpp file with which you wish to create .pch file, the .cpp file can have other useful contents after the line of `#pragma hdrstop`. When you firstly compile this .cpp file with /Yc compilation option, you get the .pch file and the .obj file. When You alter the .cpp file and recompile it with /Yu compilation option, the compiler replaces the contents befor the line of `#pragma hdrstop` with the .pch file and recompile the part after the line of `#pragma hdrstop`, create a new .obj file, saving compilation time.  It is very useful that your project has the only one source file.

For source files only using precompile head files, the `#pragma hdrstop` is a landmark for the compiler which part should be replaced by the .pch file, so you needn't indicate the header file name with /Yu compilation option.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is making *some* sense. So You have to compile the *same* cpp file with different compiler switches for this to make sense?

Comment: Yes. A C/C++ project can use more than one .pch files. You can specify the .pch for every source file by the /Yu compilation option or the #pragma hdrstop.

Comment: That much I understood. What I meant to ask was: To have this make sense, to we have one `U.cpp` that is always compiled with `/Yu` and another `C.cpp` that is always compiled with `/Yc`? *Or* do we have one single `UC.cpp` that is compiled once with `/Yc` and then with `/Yu`??