# How to include an header automatically in all cpp files in visual studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, memory-leaks, msbuild

I would like to include an header in all cpp files of my project without to change all cpp files manually in visual studio. Does someone can help me ?

I need this feature cuz I will use Visual Leaks Detector and I need to include "vld.h" in all cpp files of a huge project.

I know that I can do that with gcc/make ([Is there any way to include a header file in all C or CPP file automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639928/is-there-any-way-to-include-a-header-file-in-all-c-or-cpp-file-automatically))

Comment: Is there any header that is already included in all cpp ?

Comment: Do you have precompiled headers enabled (it is the default)? Then just include it in `"stdafx.h"`?

Comment: You could have a programmer write a program which appends a line of text at the beginning of a text file. That should be trivial enough even for inexperienced programmers.

Comment: AFAIK you need to include "vld.h" only in one single .cpp file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `/FI[name]`: *Force include* (equivalent to `-include` for gcc) in
`Configuration properties / C/C++ / Advanced / Forced Include`